# How to type props for css theming in emotion

Tags: reactjs, emotion

I am using emotion, and react.

I am defining a theme, and trying to use it across my component.

the problem is, the props from css is not typed :

```
const ButtonA = styled('button')`
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.color}; <= no type
`
```

```
 css={theme => ({ marginRight: theme.spacing })} <= no type
```

I came across this issue, and try to look around.
https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/1197

I made the following `emotion.d.ts`

```
import '@emotion/react';
import '@emotion/core';

declare global {
  namespace Emotion {
    export interface Theme {
      gap: {
        XL: string;
        L: string;
        M: string;
        S: string;
        XS: string;
      };
      colors: {
        white: string;
        background: string;
        border: string;
        success: string;
        font: string;
      };
      size: {
        button: {
          width: {
            MIN: string;
          };
          height: {
            M: string;
          };
        };
      };
    }
  }
}

declare module '@emotion/core' {
  export interface Theme {
    gap: {
      XL: string;
      L: string;
      M: string;
      S: string;
      XS: string;
    };
    colors: {
      white: string;
      background: string;
      border: string;
      success: string;
      font: string;
    };
    size: {
      button: {
        width: {
          MIN: string;
        };
        height: {
          M: string;
        };
      };
    };
  }
}
```

which is added in type roots

```
    "typeRoots": ["./src/types", "node_modules/@types"],
```

but still nothing is typed. What am I missing ?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: hey, sorry I changed project since, and I do not remember if I found or not a solution to this issue or I just did a workaround.